# Using formulas within RC formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-r1c1-notation

I'm creating a spreadsheet and need to find a way to change a formula based upon certain selection criteria. The user needs to select one of 4 options. The options are Class: 4, 5, 6 or 7.

Based upon the class selected, calculations further down are then required to look at different cell, the current spreadsheet has them all in order and moved down by a single cell. I'm using RC nomenclature in the spreadsheet.

The formula that I've come up with is as follows:

`=(R[-259]C+R[-249 + vlookup(R[-394]C,Spline,2,FALSE)]C)/2`

Now clearly I can't use this as it wont accept the equation are valid. Is there a way that this can be done. The spreadsheet can't use macro unfortunately. The vlookup would ideally be a block mover for the formula, so if the spline class is 5 rather than 4 then the formula is looking for cell that is 248 above rather than 249. I've had spent some time online and can't find a answer to my question, maybe its not possible or I'm not searching for the correct information.

For details, the table called "spline" can be seen below.

| Spline Class | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |

I hope that makes sense?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'd be better off with an INDEX formula - something like: `=(R[-259]C+INDEX(R[-249]C:R[-246]C,R[-394]C-3))/2`

Comment: @Rory thank you so much that worked perfectly. If you set that as an answer I'll mark it off as answered.